# Repeating over a transclusion in Angular - best practice to access current item?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have written the following directive:

```
transclude: true,
scope: { items: '=' }
...
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it legal / good practice to do the following when using this directive?

```
cakes = [ { name: 'blueberry cheesecake', color: 'blue' }, { name: 'rocky road', color: 'mostly brown' } ]
...
<custom-list items="cakes">
  <h5>{{$parent.item.name}}</h5>
</custom-list>
```

I am specifically talking about the `$parent.` aspect.

Comment: I would also like to know if it is fine to use $parent here, or is there a different/better way to structure the directive to achieve the same thing without requiring $parent?

Comment: making the view aware of the inner workings of the directive, namely knowing that it calls the thing "item" is not good. It doesn't seem like this scenario warrants the need for a directive.

Comment: Do you must have `<h5>{{$parent.item.name}}</h5>` in the HTML or can we bring this into the directive?

Comment: @jw56578 the HTML is simplified for the demo. There are several ancestor and sibling elements in reality. Is best practice really to repeat this boilerplate code throughout the site?

Comment: Although, I tend to agree with @jw56578, there are cases where it's OK to expose the inner `item` - for example, as a template variable, but it's the `$parent` that is problematic in my eyes. It assumes a scope hierarchy of the directive that you wouldn't want to expose to outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular have recognised that a more flexible `ng-transclude` would be beneficial:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5489

One of the suggested workarounds is to define your own override for `ng-transclude` that allows you to do the following:

```
<div ng-transclude="sibling"></div> <!-- Original behaviour -->
<div ng-transclude="parent"></div> <!-- Takes from where transclusion happens -->
<div ng-transclude="child"></div> <!-- Takes from where transclusion happens, but creates a new child scope -->
```

Source for custom `ng-transclude`:

```
.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator('ngTranscludeDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        // Remove the original directive
        $delegate.shift();
        return $delegate;
    }]);
})

.directive( 'ngTransclude', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs, controller, $transclude ) {
      if (!$transclude) {
        throw minErr('ngTransclude')('orphan',
         'Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! ' +
         'No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. ' +
         'Element: {0}',
         startingTag($element));
      }

      var iScopeType = $attrs['ngTransclude'] || 'sibling';

      switch ( iScopeType ) {
        case 'sibling':
          $transclude( function( clone ) {
            $element.empty();
            $element.append( clone );
          });
          break;
        case 'parent':
          $transclude( $scope, function( clone ) {
            $element.empty();
            $element.append( clone );
          });
          break;
        case 'child':
          var iChildScope = $scope.$new();
          $transclude( iChildScope, function( clone ) {
            $element.empty();
            $element.append( clone );
            $element.on( '$destroy', function() {
              iChildScope.$destroy();
            });            
          });
          break;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I was to generalize the problem you are trying to solve, I would say that you are trying to create a `customList` directive that allows the user to specify the template for each item.

`transclude` doesn't seem like it was meant for this - it was meant to transclude the content from the outside scope - not to backward-access the inner scope of the directive.

So, conceptually, you could do something like the following:

```
.directive("customList", function() {

  return {
    scope: {
      items: "="
    },
    templateUrl: function(element){
      element.data("customListTemplate", element.find("item-template"));
      return "customList.html";
    },
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var template = element.data("customListTemplate");
      tElement.find("item-placeholder").replaceWith(template.contents());
    }
  };
});
```

`customList.html` is:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <item-placeholder></item-placeholder>
</div>
```

And the usage is:

```
<custom-list items="cakes">
  <item-template>
    {{$index}} | {{item.name}}
    <hr>
  </item-template>
</custom-list>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p6bNjPhH9EHjdv0djXMB?p=preview)

Comment: Nice solution - this would actually work very well when you need more than one template :)

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield, wasn't that the whole point of your question? - that you wanted to specify the template as the user of the directive?

Comment: This does solve the problem, yes. What I am saying is: your solution allows an additional dimension of flexibility over using ng-transclude because you could define multiple points to substitute with template content, whereas with ng-transclude you can obviously only declare it once within a directive - if that makes sense? E.g. <col-1-template /><col-2-template />

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield, ah, yes - you could custom-templatize every part of your `customList` :)

Comment: Just tried this out for a different directive - found that the `var template` will be shared across all directive instances, so won't work if you use multiple directives on the same page.

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield, true. I fixed it by attaching the template to each templatized element. See updated answer and plunker

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield, feel free to mark as answer :)

Comment: Whilst this is a great solution for another problem (i.e. using multiple transclusion points), I feel that my own answer tackles the more specific problem of defining which scope to be used by `ng-transclude` :)

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield, then, respectfully, I would strongly recommend writing a complete answer, because right now it is mostly a link-answer.